# Reversing words in a file

Tags: c

Could someone hint to me what I'm doing wrong?I tried compiling it but im not sure what's wrong here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
  int k, i, j, len;
  FILE *f;
  char aux, str[100];

  f = fopen("rev.txt", "r");
  len = strlen(str);
  if (f == NULL) {
    printf("File not found!");
    return 0;
  }

  while (fgets(str, 80, f) != NULL) {
    for (j = 0; j < len; j++)
      if ((isalpha(str[j]) != 1) || (j == len - 1))
        if (j < len - 1)
          k = j - 1;
        else
          k = j;
    i = 0;
    while (i < k) {
      aux = str[i];
      str[i] = str[k];
      str[k] = aux;
      i++;
      k--;
    }

    printf("%s",str);
  }
}
```

So in the above code I tried reversing words from a file named rev but whenever I run it it will print weird characters. Any help?

Comment: maybe you destroyed the nul termination char? start by creating a [mcve]

Comment: @lola What value do you expect for `len` after this code: `char aux, str[100]; ...
  len = strlen(str);`?

Answer (score 5):

Properly indenting the code, and turning on warnings, reveals the problem. You're using `for` and `if` without blocks. While this is legal, it is very easy to get wrong. In particular...

```
    for(j=0;j<len;j++)
        if ((isalpha(str[j])!=1) || (j==len-1))
    if(j<len-1)
        k=j-1;
    else
        k=j;
    i=0;
```

I'm honestly not sure what the proper bracing is here. My compiler has warned about a ["dangling else"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) so something isn't right.

```
test.c:21:9: warning: add explicit braces to avoid dangling else [-Wdangling-else]
        else
```

I suspect you meant this.

```
    for(j=0;j<len;j++) {
        if((isalpha(str[j])!=1) || (j==len-1)) {
            if(j<len-1) {
                k=j-1;
            }
            else {
                k=j;
            }
        }
    }
```

Either way, always use blocks. Always compile with warnings. I use `-Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c99 -pedantic`.

---

Another issue is this:

```
len = strlen(str);
```

At this point `str` is uninitialized so it will contain garbage. `len` will be the length of that garbage.

`len` will also never change, yet the content of `str` changes with each line read. Instead you need to check the length of `str` inside the loop just after each `fgets` call.

```
while(fgets(str,80, f) != NULL) {
    len = strlen(str);
    ...
}
```

---

Your `str` buffer is 100, but you're only allowing `fgets` 80 characters. To avoid this, use `sizeof(str)` instead of hard coding. Note: this only works with stack allocated memory.

```
while(fgets(str, sizeof(str), f) != NULL) {
    len = strlen(str);
```

While you're at it, there's no reason to be stingy with a line buffer. It's only allocated once. 80 or 100 is very small for a line buffer. Give it 4096 bytes to allow for very long lines.

---

With these fixes your code works, but we can improve on it. In particular that whole `for` loop seems unnecessary. I suspect all it's doing is trying to keep the newline on the end of the reversed string. There's no need to look through the whole string. `fgets` reads line by line, if there is a newline it will always be on the end.

```
// Convert the length to an index
k = strlen(str) - 1;

// Leave the trailing newline alone
if( str[k] == '\n' ) {
    k--;
}
```

With that, plus better variable names, only declaring variables as needed, and using the proper types, we get...

```
while(fgets(str, sizeof(str), f) != NULL) {
    // Check if someone snuck a null byte into the file.
    if( !*str ) {
        continue;
    }

    // Convert the length to an index
    size_t back = strlen(str) - 1;

    // Leave the trailing newline alone
    if( str[back] == '\n' ) {
        back--;
    }

    // Swap characters
    size_t front = 0;
    while(front < back) {
        char tmp   = str[front];
        str[front] = str[back];
        str[back]  = tmp;
        front++;
        back--;
    }

    printf("%s",str);
}
```

This can be simplified even further using pointers instead of indexes.

```
while(fgets(str, sizeof(str), f) != NULL) {
    // A pointer to the last character of str
    char *back = &str[strlen(str) - 1];

    // Leave the trailing newline alone
    if( *back == '\n' ) {
        back--;
    }

    // Swap characters
    for(
        char *front = str;
        front < back;
        front++, back--
    ) {
        char tmp = *front;
        *front   = *back;
        *back    = tmp;
    }

    printf("%s",str);
}
```

Comment: @chux I think all its doing is leaving the newline on the end of the string. That can be greatly simplified, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Corner case: `size_t back = strlen(str) - 1;  if( str[back] == '\n' )` is a big problem (UB) should code first read a _null character_ then `str[SIZE_MAX]` is attempted.  Although I doubt OP will be encountering such pathological files or hacker early in their studies - so no worries for now.

Comment: @chux What's needed is a check if `strlen(str) == 0`?

Comment: Yes, of course that is simply `if (!*str )` .  I mention this primarily because there are many more hackers out there trying to break code.  Also text files in UTF-16 BE (which _shouldn't_ be read here) readily start with a leading _null character_